# Full text search MySQL randomly fails

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, innodb

I'm trying to use MySQL Full Text Search with InnoDB table. I've the required indexes. The table is very simple, just few columns.

```
CREATE TABLE `units` (
  `UnitId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(15) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `ShortName` VARCHAR(5) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UnitId`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Name` (`Name`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_ShortName` (`ShortName`) USING BTREE,
  FULLTEXT KEY `UNITS_NAME_FTS_IDX` (`Name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `UNITS_SHORTNAME_FTS_IDX` (`ShortName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=31 CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

The following query is executed

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`UnitId`, 
`Extent1`.`Name`, 
`Extent1`.`ShortName`
FROM `units` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE 
 ((MATCH(`Extent1`.`Name`) AGAINST ('kilometer*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) > 0) OR 
 ((MATCH(`Extent1`.`ShortName`) AGAINST ('kilometer*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) > 0)
LIMIT 20
```

There are just few rows in the table.

```
'26', 'Kilometer', 'km'
'27', 'Meter', 'm'
'28', 'Liter', 'l'
'29', 'Kilogram', 'kg'
'30', 'Gram', 'g'
```

These rows are constantly deleted and re-added during test execution. For most of the time the query returns the rows I'm looking for. But for some reason it randomly starts failing and stops returning any rows. They get score = 0, then. The same happens for other tables.

I know about the external FTS search engines, but I may be unable to use them. I'd prefer not to use MyISAM engine.

What may be the reason for the failures? Am I missing something?

EDIT:
Rebuilding the FTS indexes doesn't help. The query fails both in Entity Framework and console.

Comment: If this is a repeatable situation, please file a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: Thanks, Rick. I recently did.
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76357&thanks=4

Yes, it's repeatable situation. Right now more of our tests failed. Started for no reason. All FTS related :(